# Do I need to specify a base class in the symbol properties?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I've already specified in the symbol's package which class the symbol's class extends, do I still need to specify the base class in the symbol properties dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to, no.  Flash will take the base class from the class that you specify in the properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to specify the base class - especially if you think you might use the same class for different symbols in the library.

**EG** if you just define the symbol's class in the "Class" property, you will run into issues later if you try to assign a different symbol that class as well.

It makes your code more re-useable if you use the base class and then add the symbol to the stage using [getDefinitionByName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29).